# WebP not working on mobile, but working on Desktop?

Tags: modernizr, google-pagespeed, webp

I converted all my images to WebP using `gulp-webp`and I'm using Modernizr to check if webp is enabled and if so, create a new img tag with the webp url. It's working as intended on desktop as far as I can see on Google Page Speed, but on mobile, it says `Serve images in next-gen formats` still.

Is there another step you have to take for it to work on mobile devices? I can't find anything about it anywhere and I've set up webp exactly as Modernizr says.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Modernizr.on('webp', function (result) {
    $('.noscript').each(function() {
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        img.alt = this.getAttribute('data-alt');
        img.className = this.getAttribute('data-class');

        if (result) {
            img.src = this.getAttribute('data-webp');
        } else {
            img.src = this.getAttribute('data-original');
        }

        this.parentNode.insertBefore(img, this.nextSibling);
    });
});
```

Then I'd do this in the HTML:

```
<noscript data-alt="Payment Logos" data-original="/images/common/payment-foot.png" data-webp="/dist/images/common/payment-foot.webp" data-class="mobileHide lazyload" class="noscript"> 
    <img src="/images/common/payment-foot.png" alt="" class="mobileHide">
</noscript>
```

Comment: care to share some code, odds are you have not implemented it correctly and it is downloading the jpgs and then downloading the webp. Or share a URL and I will have a look for you.

Comment: I'll update it with my modernizr script now, please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: I have been having a head scratch on this, is the URL publicly available so you can share it in the comments as the example you give is fine but I still think there is something wrong with your implementation that is loading the images as jpgs / pngs first.

Comment: You were right, I found the issue- for whatever reason when the original site was setup it uses different sliders than the desktop version, and they hadn't been updated with the noscript code... silly mistake. Thanks for the help